# Is this file I/O utility efficient or is there a lot of fat?

Tags: java, io

This is a class/method that manages files being written to and read from. I have a lot of code, and it grew as I tried to get it to work properly. Is there a better way to write this (i.e. trim the fat) or is it written properly?

```
import java.io.*;

public class DataBase {
public static String getExtension(File f) {
    String ext = null;
    String s = f.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
        ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ext;
}

public static String readFile(String file) {
    String data = "";
    if (!new java.io.File(file).exists()) {
        return data;
    }
    File f = new File(file);
    FileInputStream fStream = null;
    BufferedInputStream bStream = null;
    BufferedReader bReader = null;
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        fStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        bStream = new BufferedInputStream(fStream);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bStream));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = bReader.readLine())!=null) {
            //line = bReader.readLine();

            if (line.length() > 0) {
                if (line.contains("<br/>")) {
                    line = line.replaceAll("<br/>", " ");
                    String tempLine = "";
                    while ((tempLine.trim().length() < 1)
                            && bStream.available() != 0) {
                        tempLine = bReader.readLine();
                    }
                    line = line + tempLine;
                }
                buff.append(line += "\n");

            }
        }

        fStream.close();
        bStream.close();
        bReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buff.toString();

}

public static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, String data,
        boolean append) {
    boolean isWrite = false;
    int dirIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(getPathSeparator());
    if (dirIndex != -1) {
        String dir = fileName.substring(0, dirIndex) + getPathSeparator();
        java.io.File fDir = new java.io.File(dir);
        if (!fDir.exists()) {
            if (!fDir.mkdirs()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        java.io.FileOutputStream fout = new java.io.FileOutputStream(
                fileName, append);
        java.nio.channels.FileChannel fChannelWriter = fout.getChannel();
        byte[] bytesToWrite = data.getBytes();
        java.nio.ByteBuffer bBuffW = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesToWrite);
        fChannelWriter.write(bBuffW);
        fChannelWriter.close();
        fout.close();
        isWrite = true;
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Occured: Unable to write to file ("
                + fileName + ")");
        isWrite = false;
    }
    return isWrite;
}


public static String getPathSeparator() {
    return java.io.File.separator;
}
}
```

Comment: Utility classes tend to be an anti-pattern. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AntiPattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataBase` is a poor name for a collection of file I/O convenience routines.  Especially one whose `readFile()` function swallows empty lines and strips `<br/>` tags as it reads.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this class?  I suspect that you have decomposed your problem poorly, and this class shouldn't exist.

---

The `getExtension()` function could be more succinct.

```
public static String getExtension(File f) {
    String s = f.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    return (i > 1 && i < s.length() - 1) ?
        s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase() :
        null;
}
```

I've changed the condition from `i > 0` to `i > 1` since the names of Unix dotfiles (e.g. `.profile`) are not usually thought of as file extensions.  That's a judgement call for you to make.

---

I think your `readFile()` should take a `File` rather than a `String` parameter.  If you design your API so that you consistently use `File` to represent file paths and `String` to represent file content data, then it will be harder to accidentally call your function with swapped arguments (especially for `writeToFile()`).  Also, if you call the other function `writeToFile()`, then you should rename `readFile()` to `readFromFile()` for consistency.

Swallowing exceptions is usually a bad idea, even if you print the stack trace.  I would just let any `IOException`s propagate.

You're just using the default character encoding, so you don't need to bother with constructing `InputStream`s — just use `Reader`s.

Testing for `String.contains()` before doing `String.replaceAll()` just repeats the work needlessly.  `String.replaceAll()` will just return the original string anyway if no replacement needs to be performed.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with the `tempLine` stuff.  Since you initialize `tempLine = ""`, it will always be true that `tempLine.trim().length()` is 0, so all of that is dead code.

Assuming you don't need thread safety, just use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Doing a string concatenation in `buff.append(line + "\n")` defeats the efficiency gains of using a `StringBuffer`.

All together…

```
public static String readFromFile(File f) throws IOException {
    if (!f.exists()) {
        // I find this behavior surprising; I would have expected a
        // FileNotFoundException to be thrown instead.
        return "";
    }

    FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(r);
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                line = line.replaceAll("<br/>", " ");
                buff.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
        r.close();
    }
}
```

The code could be a bit less clumsy if you use Java 7's try-with blocks.

---

`writeToFile()` can be simplified by a lot.  For simplicity, I would just use a `FileWriter` instead of the `java.nio` API.

```
public static void writeToFile(File f, String data, boolean append) throws IOException {

    File parent = f.getParentFile();
    if (!parent.exists()) {
        parent.mkdirs();
    }

    FileWriter w = new FileWriter(f, append);
    try {
        w.write(data);
    } finally {
        w.close();
    }
}
```

---

With the simplification to `writeToFile()`, `getPathSeparator()` might not be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2):

First of all name your variables properly. Name of the variable should describe what it is, but `f` is just a random letter not a name for variable.

Consider using logger instead of printing to sout.

Stream closing should go to the [finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block not in try.

You are nesting a lot of loops and ifs. Try to separate it into methods soo you and up with

```
while (line = ...) {
  processLine(line);
}

void processLine(String) {
 if (...) {
  method1();
 } else {
  method2();
 }
}
```

I also think that methods like `writeToFile()` Should take a File instance as an argument - it should be responsible for writing to the file not opening it or creating some directories. Same for readFile method.